# How to clear iPhone simulator copy & paste clipboard?

Tags: iphone, clipboard

I was debugging a defect which occurs, when clipboard is empty (could see popup triangle without popup, possibly system defect). As part of examining the defect I **copied something on clipboard** and now would **need to clear it**... but how?

Shutting down simulator and restarting did not clear clipboard. Have to say it's pretty funny not to be able to do such a "simple" task :)

Before anyone suggests, copying space or some other whitespace character will not be enough. I need it to be empty, not just non-visible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can reset the simulator to "factory defaults".

Click on "iOS Simulator" in the menu bar and select the third option from the top.

Comment: Thanx! Lost test files (photos, videos) inside simulator, but it's worth the clipboard reset. Hopefully next simulator will allow more detailed reset :)

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to copying whitespace, but more effective (and less destructive than The-Kenny's solution). You can paste an empty string to the clipboard, something like:

```
[pasteboard setString:@""];
```

Once your program runs this line of code, the "Paste" option will no longer appear in the pop up triangle menu. I have been using this exact method while testing my code, and it works great. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to simply set the text, image or whatever, to NULL before the code that you need to fix.  This clears the pasteboard completely.